# Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) Isn't Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I have recently been making an inventory system, but I can't manage to get the UI to show up with Input.GetKeyDown like I've wanted to. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject invUI;
    public GameObject soulFragmentPanel;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            invUI.SetActive(true);
            soulFragmentPanel.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E))
        {
            invUI.SetActive(false);
            soulFragmentPanel.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (invUI.activeSelf)
        {
            soulFragmentPanel.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you release the `E` key, you close the UI. Plus you said `GetKeyDown` but you wrote in code `GetKey`. Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: Oh oops lol, I forgot to remove that and change it to GetKeyDown. I was testing to see if that would work, and it didn't. Also, I have tried commenting out the GetKeyUp, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: So, when you press `E`, is your `GameObject` enabled in the hierarchy ? Maybe parents are disabled ? Is the content of `invUI` what you wanted ? Is any of his children disabled ? Is `invUI` off screen in some ways (`x`, `y` location, wrong layer, something above, ...) ?

Comment: Can you post screen shots of what you want to achieve and what is actually happening... also can you post screen shots of the hierarchy so we can the state of the objects while debugging.

Comment: @Malphegal Nope, isn't enabling in the hierarchy. I seriously don't know what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check in unity? you turn off that object which contains the **Inventory** script.

you have to set the **invUI** and **soulFragmentPanel** in single canvas and take **Inventory** script in that canvas.

so your code is working properly.

Comment: Thank you so much! After a little tweaking off of what you said, I got it to work how I wanted it to!